# Vue3 - Inherited property from parent

Tags: vuejs3

I'm creating some components, is there a way that I can propagate a reaonly property to all nested(with nested components) without needing to declare a 'readonly:boolean' property in every component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `provide('name', var)` in your parent component and
`const var = inject('name')` in your descendant components:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html